# validate input using regex pattern

Tags: html, regex

I want to validate phone number like this

1. 08xxxxxxxx
2. 08xxxxxxxxxx
3. 08xxxxxxxxxxxxx

first and second digit must be `08` and following with other digits minimum 10 digit and maximum 15 digit

I already tried this code

```
<form>
<input type="tel" name="no_hp" class="form-control" pattern="[0]{1}[8]{1}[0-9]" maxlength="15" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Nomor telepon harus di awali dengan 08 dan minimal 10')" required>
 
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

in below video, I try to input `089` and it successes but try without minimum 10 digit

[image]

but in below video If I try to input wrong first number like `189` and then I update to right number same with first video `089`, its still says number is wrong.

[image]

so why after I correct format the number (leading by `08`), it still says number is wrong? how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the following regex as a pattern on the input field directly or use `javascript` to do the same and show a warning message to the user.

##### JS Approach

```js
const regex = new RegExp('^08[0-9]{8,13}$', 'gm');
if (regex.test('088884444714255')) {
  console.log('valid number');
}else{
  console.log('invalid number');
}

if (regex.test('0888844447142555')) {
  console.log('valid number');
}else{
  console.log('invalid number');
}

if (regex.test('078844447142555')) {
  console.log('valid number');
}else{
  console.log('invalid number');
}
```

##### HTML Pattern Approach

```html
<form>
  <input type="tel" name="no_hp" class="form-control" pattern="^08[0-9]{8,13}$" oninvalid=" this.setCustomValidity('Nomor telepon harus di awali dengan 08 dan minimal 10')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: is it possible if only use html without javascript?

Comment: @E-Place I've updated my answer, to show you both `js` & `html` approaches.

Comment: I tried in my program and I `run code snippet` from your code, it's same error. please see the video https://gifyu.com/image/e5uJ

Comment: Woops! I limited it to `[0-8]` previously. it should have been `[0-9]`. Corrected now.

Comment: ooh it's work. but if I try custom message using `oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Nomor telepon harus di awali dengan 08 dan minimal 10')"` , it's always false when after I corrected the number. like second video in my question. or have other way to custom message?

Comment: Just use `oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"` to reset the value everytime the input changes. I've updated the same in the answer snippet. Please check.